# How to view public Instagram photos without signing in?

Tags: instagram

When you link to a public Instagram account, the site will allow you to view photos for a  few seconds before obscuring the entire page, locking scroll and popping up a box asking you to sign in. I do not have or want to create an Instagram account but would like to be able to view the photos. What's a good back for this?

I know I can inspect element and delete it to clear the overlay but scroll will still be locked. Blocking JS with noscript also does not work as the photos don't show.